# Does class method definition carry over separate unit tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

*Using Rails 5.0.7.2 and Minitest 5.1.*

I was writing multiple unit tests and looked for possible ways to stub a method call (not the question here). I decided to redefine my class method:

```
def Foo.bar
  class << self
    false
  end
end
```

Then out of caution, we were wondering whether this method redefinition would carry over other distinct tests. This latter behaviour should not happen since unit tests are isolated, but we wanted to confirm this.

Comment: The correct question is: "does `@payment_method` survive across tests"? The answer is "depends on how you set its value". In rspec, we have `before :each` and `before :all` setup blocks. This `def setup` looks like it's executed before each test (but I'm not too familiar with minitest to say with 100% certainty)

Comment: Right, thanks for pointing this out. I'll redefine a class method instead of an instance method.

Comment: `def @payment_method.usable?` makes absolutely no sense.  `usable?` should return a boolean so its basically equivilent to `def true/false`. Is this even syntactically valid? If you do this in a class body you're also actually referencing the class instance variable `@payment_method` and not an instance variable.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Question and answer have been edited accordingly, using PaymentMethod instead of @payment_method.

Comment: Why would you even do this in the first place instead of using a mocking library?  What you're doing is going to have side effects and bite you in bottom. https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/mocking-in-ruby-with-minitest

Comment: Thanks, I needed this reading :)

Comment: @max: it is actually perfectly valid ruby code. Not any different from, say, `def self.usable?` you'd write for a class method.

Comment: Thanks guys for pointing out the mistakes in my research. I have edited both my question and answer with a whole new class, and found out the correct answer is YES.
Of course, we're definitely going for a proper mocking library, for clearer tests.
I wanted to satisfy my curiosity before. :)

Answer (score 0):

I edited a sample of tests, showed as followed:

```js
class Foo
  class << self
    def bar
      true
    end
  end
end

class FooTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test "A" do
    puts "TEST A"
    def Foo.bar
      class << self
        false
      end
    end
    refute Foo.bar
  end

  test "B" do
    puts "TEST B"
    assert Foo.bar
  end

end
```

We want **Test A** to redefine our method, then observe **Test B**'s consistency. Depending on the test order, we get different results.

```js
# Running:

TEST B
.TEST A
  2/2: [===========================================================================================================================================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00
.
Finished in 0.00341s
2 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

```js
# Running:

TEST A
.TEST B
 FAIL FooTest#test_B (0.00s)
        Expected false to be truthy.
        test/models/tmp_test.rb:27:in `block in <class:FooTest>'

  2/2: [===========================================================================================================================================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00
F

Failure:
FooTest#test_B [/home/grapstor/store/kevin/test/models/tmp_test.rb:27]:
Expected false to be truthy.


bin/rails test test/models/tmp_test.rb:25


Finished in 0.00342s
2 tests, 2 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

So, can I assume the correct response is **yes, and we should go for a doubles ASAP**?

Comment: Yes, absolutely use doubles/mocks instead of this.